# Subqueries for each row

Tags: sql, nested, subquery

Using these tables:

***student {'s_id','s_name,'...} , class {'c_id','c_name',...} student2class {'s_id','c_id'}, grades {'s_id','c_id','grade'}***

Is it possible to perform a query (nested query?) put class name as subtitle and then all students (of that class) and grades, next class name as subtitle ...

The result I need is:

### Maths

John .... C

Anna .... B

[...]

### Biology

Anna .... C

Jack .... A

[...]

For each row from class I'll have a subquery fetching all data related with this class

Comment: I believe that the purpose of a query is to get (fetch) all the required data. Presentation layer (client application, report writer, etc.) should worry about the exact formatting.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari This is definitely not something that a DBA should be looking into (it fits here on SO). Either way, PM77-1 is right, this should be done on the presentation layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of any sub-query. You can get your data this way:

```
SELECT c_name, s_name_, grade
FROM student, class, grades
WHERE student.s_id = grades.s_id and class.c_id = grades.c_id
ORDER BY c_name
```

The presentation of results depends on your system/tools, as others already said. This is a link to the solution for Microsoft Access:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-HA001159160.aspx

Comment: ORDER BY!! of course!...  simple and straight. Thank you Rémi

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be implemented in your client side code and not in the database. From database you should just get a simple table formatted data (subject, student, grade)

Then convert the above recordset to the format you want:
For an example in C# you could convert the recordset into lookup

var Lookup = DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.ToLookup(x => x["subjectColumn"]);

now you can loop through the lookup and format your result

foreach (var grade in Lookup)

{

subject = grade.Key;

...

}